# how to get session data from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

i work on one web application an it create lots of session. So I want to get all created session and it value there are any way to do this ?

Comment: Show your work here.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Of course there's a way to do this - ultimately you could implement your own session state manager or database and make it queryable. However, without knowing exactly what your requirements are it's impossible to advise you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this methods 1st method

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
{
    var crntSession = Session.Keys[i];
    Response.Write(string.Concat(crntSession, "=", Session[crntSession]) + "<br />");
}
```

2nd method

```
foreach (var crntSession in Session)
{
    Response.Write(string.Concat(crntSession , "=", Session[crntSession .ToString()]) + "<br />");
}
```

[more details](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Session-Variables-Values.aspx)

Comment: Second method work for me.

Comment: That will print out the key/value pairs for *the current session*. The question author wants to print out *all* sessions.

Comment: @AbiRuban Oh. Apparently I'm wrong and the question is just very poorly written! Well done for working out what he meant!